# PHP: replace 'dollar' in string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords

I have a serious problem, whole day I been looking for answers but I cannot find anything...

**What I Am Doing:**

I am trying to make a user login on my site(in php).

The passwords and users are saved in a MySQL database on my server.

For the passwords I am using *Bcrypt*. The only problem is that I do not have the knowledge to change the *Bcrypt* code.. I got the class from a free to have site.

**Problem**

Now for the problem, when I am hashing my passwords there are three `$` signs in front.

For example: `loltest` will become `$2y$10$wxadWEbkn..XpJ.C1TmnaeOyneJyQbcAIJ20yBBlBoBr1XDwDkJSq`

The hashed password is stored in a table in my database.

**Step 1**

A user logs in an typs his/her password, the php code then verifies if the password matches the hashed password. The name of a user is `$phpro_username` and the password is stored in `$phpro_password`.

But before I call that function I am selecting the hashed password from my table like this:

```
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username,      $mysql_password);    
 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT phpro_password FROM phpro_users WHERE phpro_username = '$phpro_username'");
 $stmt->execute();
 $hash = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

**Step 2**

I tried to use the function called `password_verify`, it looks like this:

```
function password_verify($password, $hash) {
    if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
        trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_verify to function", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    $ret = crypt($password, $hash);
    if (!is_string($ret) || strlen($ret) != strlen($hash) || strlen($ret) <= 13) {
        return false;
    }

    $status = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($ret); $i++) {
        $status |= (ord($ret[$i]) ^ ord($hash[$i]));
    }

    return $status === 0;
}
```

**How do I do it?**

```
$check = password_verify($phpro_password, $hash);
```

If the passwords match `$check` will be 1, else it will be empty.

Normally this should be working but when I am running this code the `$check` is always empty. If i try to do this without the MySQL there is no problem:

```
<?php
   include 'password.php';
   $password = "loltest";
   $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
   $verify = password_verify("loltest", $hash);
   echo $verify;
?>
```

If I run the code above for example, `$verify` is always 1.

**After some research:**

I think the problem lies with the MySQL, because in my hash are three `$` signs, if I store this in MySQL and then get it out the varibles are changed with their values, in this case nothing and the passwords do not match.

Is there a way to solve this? Or is there a way to replace the `$` signs in my hash?

Comment: Maybe collate problems.

Comment: Wrap the string in single quotes? - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php http://codepad.viper-7.com/pXQhlA

Comment: @Edward I could wrap the string in single qoutes if I know how to go from a double to a single quoted string, because my string is directly selected out of the database and I have no idea how to make it single qouted..?

Comment: htmlentities($row['something']); should do it?

Comment: @DonDjango text fetched from db is only text, it is not recognized as variable unless you eval it. Your problem is not dollar sign, but how you are trying to verify passwords. See [example on `crypt` manual](http://php.net/crypt#example-4783), there is no need for bitwise operations...

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Oh.. I am sorry.. I am a beginner -.- what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I am sorry it is password_verify and the $escapedString has to be $hash. I copied from my test page but on my real page I have the correct version but still not working..

Comment: Can you verify that `$hash` fetched from db actually contains anything? `var_dump($hash);` should output `string(60) "$2y$10$wxadWEbkn..XpJ.C1TmnaeOyneJyQbcAIJ20yBBlBoBr1XDwDkJSq"`

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Yes I can verify that it does contain something.

Comment: And is it 60 character long string that begins with `$2y$10$` ?

Comment: Yes it is. I verified twice.

Comment: At least you know now that your dollar signs are stored and retrieved from DB just as they should. Other possible problems may be two users with same `$phpro_username` but different password, hash stored in db was generated for other password, typo in your variables or variable overwrite at some point.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Hmm I think the last reason was the problem I tried to fix this and it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quote strings are not processed and are taken "as-is". You should always use single quote strings unless you specifically need the $variable.

For example,

```
$var = "$2y$10$wxadWEbkn..XpJ.C1TmnaeOyneJyQbcAIJ20yBBlBoBr1XDwDkJSq";
```

should be

```
$var = '$2y$10$wxadWEbkn..XpJ.C1TmnaeOyneJyQbcAIJ20yBBlBoBr1XDwDkJSq';
```

Comment: Yes ok, but I tried to search how to do it but I cannot find anything.. My hash is directly selected out of the MySQL database, is there a way to single qoute this value? I'm sorry for my 'stupid' questions.. I'm just starting..

Comment: I did not say that this worked? But ok yeah single quoting helps. But can I ask you another question(a small one)?

Comment: Do you know something about cookies..?

Comment: I have a lot of pages, and on my login page I define 2 cookies, one with a time of an hour and one with no time(it delays after closing). Before uploading my last page, the one with the Bcrypt code everything was working. But for some reason my cookies aren't set anymore.. And I am shure I did not changed the page where they are set or their value.. Do you know why..?